# Issue using uwsgi with Conda environment

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi, supervisord, conda

I'm trying to run a Flask app in a conda environment with uwsgi, started by supervisor.

My uwsgi config file looks like

**myflaskapp.ini**

```
[uwsgi]
uid = 1001
gid = 1001
master = true
processes = 2
chmod-socket = 666
pid-file = /home/me/Development/flask/myflaskapp/run/myflaskapp.pid
socket = /home/me/Development/flask/myflaskapp/run/myflaskapp.sock
module = wsgi
callable = app
logdate = true
```

and the supervisor config file looks like

**uwsgi-myflaskapp.conf**

```
[program:uwsgi-myflaskapp]
command=/home/me/Development/miniconda/envs/myenv/bin/uwsgi /home/me/Development/flask/myflaskapp/myflaskapp.ini
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/home/me/Development/flask/myflaskapp/log/uwsgi-myflaskapp.log
redirect_stderr=true
exitcodes=0
```

When reloading supervisor (`sudo supervisorctl reload`) I get the following error in the log file:

```
Mon Jan 11 15:48:29 2016 - Python version: 2.7.11 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Dec  6 2015, 18:08:32)  [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 563, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 545, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 272, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 247, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 237, in getuserbase
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 578, in get_config_var
    return get_config_vars().get(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 524, in get_config_vars
    _init_posix(_CONFIG_VARS)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 408, in _init_posix
    from _sysconfigdata import build_time_vars
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_sysconfigdata.py", line 6, in <module>
    from _sysconfigdata_nd import *
ImportError: No module named _sysconfigdata_nd
```

First question: why is it using `/usr/lib/python2.7` and not Python from the conda environment? Is it not enough to use the uwsgi bin from my conda environment in the supervisor config to set the conda environment? If not, how can I set the conda environment?

Second question: how can I fix this error?

Comment: At a glance it could be defaulting to */usr* python stuff because of your *sudo supervis....*. e.g. type python vs sudo python at the terminal, you get anaconda and default linux pythons respectively. It could be helpful in debugging.

Comment: Did you install supervisor in the conda env?

Comment: Perhaps this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15293801/supervisor-not-working-with-gunicorn-flask

Comment: I tried to install supervisor in the conda env but could not find how to configure the service (no conf.d).